# Length of float changes between 32 and 40 bit

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I encountered an odd problem when exporting `float` values to a file. I would expect every float to be of the same length (obviously), but my programme sometimes exports it a 32 bit number and sometimes as a 40 bit number.
A minimal working example of a programme that still shows this behaviour is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* fileName = "C:/Users/Path/To/TestFile.txt";
float array [5];

int main(int argc, char* argv [])
{
    float temp1 = 1.63006e-33f;
    float temp2 = 1.55949e-32f;

    array[0] = temp1;
    array[1] = temp2;
    array[2] = temp1;
    array[3] = temp2;
    array[4] = temp2;

    FILE* outputFile;
    if (!fopen_s(&outputFile, fileName, "w")) 
    {
        fwrite(array, 5 * sizeof(float), 1, outputFile);
        fclose(outputFile);
    }

     return true;
}
```

I would expect the output  file to contain exactly 20 (5 times 4) bytes, each four of which represent a float. However, I get this:

```
 8b 6b 07 09      // this is indeed 1.63006e-33f 
 5b f2 a1 0d 0a   // I don't know what this is but it's a byte too long
 8b 6b 07 09      
 5b f2 a1 0d 0a   
 5b f2 a1 0d 0a
```

So the float `temp2` takes 5 bytes instead of four, and the total length of he file is 23. How is this possible?! The number aren't so small that they are subnormal numbers, and I can't think of any other reason why there would be a difference in size.

I am using the MSVC 2010 compiler on a 64-bit Windows 7 system.

**Note:** *I already asked a very similar question here, but when I realised the problem was more general, I decided to repost it in a more concise way.*
[QDataStream uses sometimes 32 bit and sometimes 40 bit floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704276/qdatastream-uses-sometimes-32-bit-and-sometimes-40-bit-floats)

Comment: Basically, never open any file with `fopen` without `b`.

Comment: Just be glad one of your test values wasn't `0.5392157`!

Comment: [Binary and Text Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229924/difference-between-files-writen-in-binary-and-text-mode#)

Comment: try changing .txt to something else and working in binary mode

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that on Windows, you have to differentiate between text and binary files. You have the file opened as text, which means `0d` (carriage-return) is inserted before every `0a` (line-feed) written. Open the file like this:

```
if (!fopen_s(&outputFile, fileName, "wb"))
```

The rest as before, and it should work.

Comment: This is amazing, this one letter solved everything (i.e. two days of banging my head against a wall).

Comment: Don't worry, we all have that feel sometimes.

Comment: Also, if you are writing a binary file, you probably shouldn't give it a ".txt" extension. That will simply confuse everybody.

Answer (score 12):

You're not writing text; you're writing binary data... However, your file is open for *writing text* (`"w"`) instead of *writing binary* (`"wb"`). Hence, `fwrite()` is translating `'\n'` to `"\r\n"`.

Change this:

```
if (!fopen_s(&outputFile, fileName, "w"))
```

To this:

```
if (!fopen_s(&outputFile, fileName, "wb"))
```

In `"wb"`, the `b` stands for binary mode.